# How to scan and get byte array with decimal values from qr code in ios?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a qr code from which i want to read and extract 180 byte hexadecimal value, mine is an ionic app, and i am using phonegap barcode scanner in my app. When tried with this qr c[image]ode scanner i am not getting any response, when i tried to debug this in xcode i found that its actually reading the qr code, and when i went to AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject -> _internal -> basicDescriptor -> BarCodeRawData

There was a data present there which was,

[40 0B 45 55 73 60 10 00 10 03 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83 93 03 13 23
33 43 53 63 73 83 93 03 03 13 22 05 24 54 54 62 02 33 10 00 01 90 5E
70 70 DO EO A3 F4 20 FO 03 F4 20 FO 00 7B 20 10 09 FB BO DO 00 10
00 1010 1B BO 8E 90 90 1F F6 90 05 06 20 2B C0 00 17DO 00 06 25
93 5635 06 2B CO 00 07 EO 07 EO 07 DO 00 27 DO O7 DO 07DO 07 DO
07 DO 07 DO 07 EO 07 DO 07 DO 07DO 06 25 9F FB BO 86 25 96 20 16
80 0356 30 17 DO 00 10 20 AO 26 25 97 E0 06 25 97 EO 00 17 DO 07 FO
07 DO 00 17 DO 07 DO 08 30 07 EO 07 EO 07 E0 00 08 06 50 06 50 06
40 06 25 9F FO EC 11 EC 11 EC 11 EC 11 EC 11 EC 11 EC 11]

But this is not the data we are expecting as raw bytes

We are expecting a byte array which have a decimal values,

I was able to get the intended result in android by using some properties,
intent.getByteArrayExtra('SCAN_RESULT_BYTE_SEGMENTS_0').

"SCAN_RESULT_BYTE_SEGMENTS_0" when i haven't given this property for Android ,result was not intended byte array with decimal values.

The actual data I want to get from this Qr code is a hexadecimal, that is:

555736010001003132333435363738393031323334353637383930303132205245454620233100001905E7070D0E0A3F420F003F420F0007B201009FBB0D000100010101BB08E90901FF6900506202BC00017D0000625935635062BC00007E007E007D00027D007D007D007D007D007D007E007D007D007D006259FFBB086259620168003563017D0001020A0262597E0062597E00017D007F007D00017D007D0083007E007E007E0000806500650064006259FF

So basically in short i am really stuck here in for ios, can someone help me out.

Comment: `We are expecting a byte array which have a decimal values,` A byte array contains bytes. Only bytes. No values. Every byte is eight bits. How you interpret the bits is up to you. You can display them as decimal, hexadecimal, octal value, what ever you want. But a byte is only eight bits.

Comment: Please edit your post and include the QR code image of your sample data so we can see what data format you use.

Comment: @Robert I have edited the question, as u suggested.  And i have added the intended output also.

Comment: Any possible solutions??